# Differences in loading of $.ajax and $.getJson

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to implement an ajax call to get some data from the server.
Earlier this data was hard coded into JS. So I am reducing the page load and get that data from the server. The data I am getting is used on many places on the page.

Now I used both `$.ajax` and `$.getJson`.

```
$.getJSON(reqUrl)
.done(function(data){
    searchvars = data;
})

$.ajax({
    url: reqUrl,
    type: 'GET'
})
.done(function(data){
    searchvars = data;
})
```

In case of `$.getJson`, everything works fine. 
But in case of `$.ajax`, it gives error of "variable not found". Which means that the `$.ajax` request is late in getting data and assigning to the "variable".

My question is why `$.getJson` works perfectly and `$.ajax` doesn't. Also do you have any better approach to this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to post some more code and information on what variable is not found before some meaningful answer can be given...

Comment: We'd need to see some code to answer this, since you're doing something wrong: `$.getJson` is simply a convenience method for calling `$.ajax` with some specific defaults common in loading JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. In your $.ajax you have set dataType = 'GET' which is wrong.

```
$.getJSON(reqUrl)
.done(function(data){
    searchvars = data;
})

$.ajax({
    url: reqUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'   
})
.done(function(data){
    searchvars = data;
})
```

Comment: Oops Sorry. Edited the question. I typed here wrong.

Comment: Then also you have to specify dataType='JSON'. dataType you have to set as you are expecting json from server.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is equivalent to the following:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

There is no reason $.ajax should behave differently from $.getJSON, if all the correct parameters are provided. Make sure you are not making any other mistake in using $.ajax.

Comment: In your $.ajax request, you need to specify dataType: 'json'.